# SwiftSoup - Extracting specific div tags/elements

Tags: html, swift, swiftsoup

I'm not the most knowledgeable when dealing with scraping/getting data from a website, so apologies in advance. I have loaded in the HTML file locally, into my project so that I can have a reference and breakdown of the elements:

```
<div class="price">99</div>
<div class="size">M</div>
```

I want to select both these div classes, name and price and extract the value(s) which are 99 and M accordingly, how can I do this? I looked at SwiftSoups

```
let elements = try doc.select("[name=transaction_id]") // query
let transaction_id = try elements.get(0) // select first element
let value = try transaction_id.val() // get value
```

But that gave me an error. I can see you can select `<P> tags,` which are paragraphs, but how do I select the specific div class?

Once again, apologies if this is a beginner question.

Thank you.

Edit - The data I wish to parse:

```
var pstats = {att1:85,att2:92,att3:91,att4:95,att5:38,att6:65,acceleration:91,agility:91,balance:95,jumping:68,reactions:94,sprintspeed:80,stamina:72,strength:69,aggression:44,positioning:93,tactaware:40,vision:95,ballcontrol:96,crossing:85,curve:93,dribbling:96,finishing:95,fkacc:94,headingacc:70,longpass:91,longshot:94,marking:32,penalties:75,shortpass:91,shotpower:86,slidetackle:24,standingtackle:35,volleys:88,composure:96};
```

Edit 2 - New data I want to parse:

```
   <div style="display: none;" id="player_stats_json">{"test":0,"ppace":85,"pshooting":92,"ppassing":91,"pdribbling":95,"pdefending":38,"pphysical":65,"acceleration":91,"sprintspeed":80,"agility":91,"balance":95,"reactions":94,"ballcontrol":96,"dribbling":96,"positioning":93,"finishing":95,"shotpower":86,"longshotsaccuracy":94,"volleys":88,"penalties":75,"interceptions":40,"headingaccuracy":70,"marking":32,"standingtackle":35,"slidingtackle":24,"vision":95,"crossing":85,"freekickaccuracy":94,"shortpassing":91,"longpassing":91,"curve":93,"jumping":68,"stamina":72,"strength":69,"aggression":44,"composure":96}</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these tags have unique classes you can use `getElementsByClass(_:)` function and then get the first item, like this:

```
let price = try doc.getElementsByClass("price").first()?.text()
let size = try doc.getElementsByClass("size").first()?.text()
```

Comment: How would I retrieve an array? The array is called var itemsArray? It's not in a class or div or anything or the sort.

Comment: Actully not too sure if it's an array it's var items = {////};

Comment: @SwiftUser could you please include in your question the raw HTML that you want to parse?

Comment: I have updated my question. Hope this helps. Once again, it's not in a div/class or anything of the sort. I believe it's local.

Comment: @SwiftUser there is something wrong with this syntax. This is not valid Swift or Objective-C code and of course not HTML. What technology are you using?

Comment: Literally, just Swift and HTML. I saved the file locally, and imported it into Swift.

Comment: @SwiftUser this is the raw Swift code that you are using? I cannot pass the compilation.

Comment: @SwiftUser or this is just a text file that you want to parse?

Comment: I literally just dragged the HTML file into Swift and this is what showed. However, I'll inspect the page document right now. Yes, just checked the console on Google Chrome and it's the exact same.

Comment: @SwiftUser so, this is a javascript line of code inside the HTML file?

Comment: Yes, I have not altered anything.

Comment: @SwiftUser OK, we are talking for something completely new. You cannot parse javascript code using SwiftSoup and I am not sure if there is anything to parse this. Perhaps asking a new question for this one will be desirable. Since, as far as I can tell, I answered your original question. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: OK, I've found an array within the HTML code itself like so: <div id="player_stats_json" /// /div> How I've managed to get it but how would I append this information to an array?

Comment: @SwiftUser could you include the corresponding HTML to your question?

Comment: I have added the HMTL, however I'm having trouble targeting that line of HTML the id "player_stats_json" as there's another div class that has the prefix `<div id="player_stats_json"` and this is one I'm getting returned as opposed to the HMTML in my question. How can I target the one in the question?

Comment: @SwiftUser the other `div` that you are getting has anything else that differentiate with this one? Maybe `class`? Could you include also that `div` in you question?

Comment: I have managed to solve the issue. However, I am having another issue with decoding the JSON value(s). I have created another question.